# Why is the completeness of the filtration needed here?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I am studying how the usual conditions of the filtration are used.
Answers in this post [In the definition of a Stopping Time, how important are the conditions on the Filtration being complete and right-continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944628/in-the-definition-of-a-stopping-time-how-important-are-the-conditions-on-the-fi) nicely explains how they are used for some hitting time or the limit of stopping times  to be a stopping time.

Now, when I was reading the answer here https://mathoverflow.net/q/229040, there is a comment saying

> Since a martingale is required to be adapted, we'll need completeness of the filtration for the conclusion from the $L^1$ convergence

Could someone elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that comment might be mistaken.  In general, we would need that the filtration is complete to ensure that $X_n(t) \rightarrow X(t)$ in $L^1$ implies $X(t)$ is $\mathcal F_t$ measurable for each $t$.  However, since the answer shows that $X(s) = \mathbb{E}[X(t)|\mathcal F_s]$, we can use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[X(t)|\mathcal F_s]$ is $\mathcal F_s$ measurable to conclude $X(s)$ is $\mathcal F_s$ measurable.

Comment: Thank you; this is getting clearer. You might be using the setting of the linked question, but are you saying that the completeness readily implies the adaptedness?

Comment: So I guess $X_n(t)\to X(t)$ in $L^1$ means $L^1$ wrt $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. And since $X(t)\in L^1$, by def. of $L^1$ it is $\mathcal{F}$-m'ble. But we are not saying anything about the (a.s.) pointwise convergence of $X_n(t)$, I don't know how I would say the $\mathcal{F}_t$-m'bility even with the completeness.

Comment: @kist $L^1$ convergence implies (a.s.) pointwise convergence along a subsequence.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, and we have the same limit. Of course... I am a bit confused even more. Isn't the lack of the completeness a problem for the usual a.s. convergence of r.v.s as well? Then we redefine the value as 0 on the measure zero set to get a r.v.

Comment: Is the problem here the following? The problematic measure zero set depends on t, and you don't want to change the value for each t because we also want to see X as a process?

Comment: @kist I think the issue is with redefining $X$ on a set of measure zero.  We want to show that $X$ is a martingale, not that a modification of $X$ is a martingale.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you very much. Things got much clearer.