# standard conditions of sigma-algebra filtrations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I recently learnt about "augmented" filtrations, i.e. filtrations of sigma-algebras $(\mathcal{F}_i)_{i\in I}$ that are both complete and right-continuous. I didn't pay much attention to it as it seemed like assuming to have a standard filtration was a good way to make things working, at no cost: in particular, of course we can enlarge the sigma algebras in the filtrations such that all null sets of $\mathcal{F}$ are contained everywhere, in particular in  $\mathcal{F}_0$ (this is "completeness"). Adding null sets cannot possibly add useful information, random variables that were measurable before are still measurable in the larger sigma-algebras, and results such the existence of cadlag versions of martingales follow in a smoother way.

Then I thought back of it and got confused. Pick for example a Poisson process, with its natural filtration. If we make the filtration complete, i.e. we add to $\mathcal{F}_0$ all null-events concerning the process, we have in $\mathcal{F}_0$ all the events of type {the nth jump of the process occurs exactly at time t}, for all natural n and all positive real t. These are events with measure 0, but they completely define the whole trajectory of the process! This disturbs me: $\mathcal{F}_0$ is only supposed to contain information about the process at time 0, plus potentially measure-zero events that should not carry too much information, but now the whole family of null events we added to $\mathcal{F}_0$ is threatening to spoil the whole trajectory of the process!

What am I missing?

Comment: Saying "$\mathcal F_0$ is complete" does not mean all null sets of $\mathcal F_\infty$ are in $\mathcal F_0$.  It means  complete with respect to the restriction of $\mathbb P$ to $\mathcal F_0$.

Comment: that is not the definition I have on the book... What book are you referring to?

Comment: "a complete measure (or, more precisely, a complete measure space) is a measure space in which every subset of every null set is measurable (having measure zero)"   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure

Comment: I agree with that, however for a filtration to be complete more is needed. Specifically, all null sets of the whole sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ need to be included in every element of the filtration $\mathcal{F}_i$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_(probability_theory)

Comment: The purpose of filtration completion is not to add more information to it. Technically this is the case but harmless since the events have probability zero. It becomes a potential problem when you consider several probability measures that are not absolutely continous w.r.t. each other and hence do not share the same null sets. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4635662/why-is-the-completeness-of-the-filtration-needed-here) mentions a typical reason why one completes a filtration.

Comment: Thank you @KurtG. for your comment! I agree with you, the reason to complete a filtration is not to add information. As I wrote in my post, I as well thought that adding null sets could not possibly cause harm. But then my confusion started when thinking that very often (see Brownian motions, or Poisson processes) the whole trajectories could be fully characterized by null events...

Comment: But the probability that we see those fully characterised trajectories is zero.

Comment: I'm still puzzled. The probability of seeing a specific trajectory is zero, but the probability of seeing one trajectory out of the many (more than countable!) ones is 1. And at time 0 we know exactly what trajectory the process will have, because any full trajectory has probability 0 of occurring hence is an event contained in $\mathcal{F}_0$.